# How can I make a image slider which stops at last image and with a replay button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make an image slider which stops at last image and with a replay button at last image using HTML CSS js only

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    currentPosition++;
}, 3000);
```

```css
#slideshow {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
            <div>
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I need to stop slider at last image and need a replay button with it.

Comment: I am not getting any solution @RasmusGlenvig

Comment: Above is my slider code

Comment: Yes I can see that :) But have you tried to solve the problem by your self, like what have you tried so far to achieve what you wan't.

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig I have tried but its not working do you have any solution?

Comment: Everyone is asking **what** you've tried not **if** you've tried. What exactly have you tried to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
function play() {
  $("#slideshow > div").hide();
  $('#slideshow > div:first').fadeIn(1000, function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).next().fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
          $(this).next().fadeIn(1000);
        })
      })
    })
  })

}
$("#replay").on("click", function() {
  play();
})

play();
```

Working fiddle here - > https://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/Lu913v34/

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentPosition = 0;
Play();    

function getCurrentImage(){
  var currentImage = $('#slideshow > div')[currentPosition];
  changeImage(currentImage);
}

function changeImage(currentImage){

  if(currentPosition != $("#slideshow > div").length + 1){

    setTimeout(function(){

      if(currentPosition == $("#slideshow > div").length - 1){
          $("#slideshow").append('<a href="#" onclick="Play();" style="margin-left:15px;">Replay</a>').fadeIn(1000);
          return;
      }

      $(currentImage).fadeOut(1000)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(1000);

      currentPosition++;
      getCurrentImage();

    },2000);
  }
}

function Play(){
  currentPosition = 0;
  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
  getCurrentImage();
}
```

Comment: but on restart it takes time to load

Comment: try this @Sonali...!

Comment: Still it is taking time.